# SQL UPDATE produces error in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two tables. Both tables have "SchoolCode" and "SchoolName" columns in common. But in one table a few "SchoolCode" are Null. I want to update the Null "SchoolCode" with the corresponding SchoolCode of other table on the basis of comparing SchoolName.

My query is :

```
update DSDClusters
set dsdclusters.EMISCodeofSchool = Censusgm.emiscode
where DSDClusters.NameofSchool = Censusgm.school_name  
  and DSDClusters.EMISCodeofSchool is null
```

But it produces error

> The multi-part identifier "Censusgm.school_name" could not be bound.

Sample of data extracted from both tables

```
emiscode    school_name     dist_nm     teh_nm    EMISCodeofSchool  NameofSchool

38410806    GPS DERA NOOR   SARGODHA    KOT MOMIN NULL              GPS DERA NOOR
38420682    GGPS ABBAS PUR  SARGODHA    SARGODHA  NULL              GGPS ABBAS PUR
38430199    GPS ISLAM PURA  SARGODHA    SHAHPUR   NULL              GPS ISLAM PURA
```

Please suggest any help

Comment: How do think that will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as a select, if it's good, run the update.

```
SELECT *
--UPDATE DS SET EMISCodeofSchool = C.emiscode
FROM DSDClusters DS
LEFT OUTER JOIN Censusgm C
   ON DS.NameofSchool = C.school_name  
WHERE DS.EMISCodeofSchool is null
```

Comment: Dear JiggsJedi,  I tried this with select but output do not produces same data from both table, School Code and Name of one table is differnet from other table shown in same row.

Comment: Can you add some sample data from both tables to your question?

Comment: emiscode school_name dist_nm teh_nm EMISCodeofSchool NameofSchool
31110376 GGPS QAZI WALA BAHAWALNAGAR              BAHAWALNAGAR              NULL GGPS QAZI WALA
31110177 GPS HAFIZ ABAD BAHAWALNAGAR              BAHAWALNAGAR              NULL GPS HAFIZ ABAD
31110242 GPS ISLAM PURA BAHAWALNAGAR              BAHAWALNAGAR              NULL GPS ISLAM PURA

Comment: Jiggs Jedi i cant post image here as i m not allowed by site, i tried to show data extracted from both tables with a query, I just want to update Null with emiscode

Comment: Why do you think my answer isn't working, what is the output of my select?

Comment: Jiggs Jedi thanks a lot, It worked, Shah Nawaz, Lahore